# delete from nth occurrence to end of file

Tags: text-processing

How do you delete from nth occurrence of a pattern to end of file using command line tools like `sed`?
e.g. delete from the third `foo` in the following:

```
something
foo1
maybe something else
foo2
maybe not
foo3 -this line and anything after is gone- 
I'm not here
```

`$sed '/magic/'`

Desired result:

```
something
foo1
maybe something else
foo2
maybe not
```

Bonus points for the same thing but keeping the line containing the third `foo`.

Comment: Assuming only one 'foo' per line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without keeping the line:

```
awk -v n=3 '/foo/{n--}; n > 0'
```

With keeping the line:

```
awk -v n=3 'n > 0; /foo/{n--}'
```

Though we may want to improve it a bit so that we quit and stop reading as soon as we've found the 3rd `foo`:

```
awk -v n=3 '/foo/{n--; if (!n) exit}; {print}' # not-keep
awk -v n=3 '{print}; /foo/{n--; if (!n) exit}' # keep
```

`sed` would be more cumbersome. You'd need to keep the count of foo occurrences as a number of characters in the hold space like:

Keep:

```
sed '
  /foo/{
    x;s/^/x/
    /x\{3\}/{
      x;q
    }
    x
  }'
```

Not keep:

```
sed -ne '/foo/{x;s/^/x/;/x\{3\}/q;x;}' -e p
```

Answer (score 2):

If you accept `perl` as a *command line tool*, you can also

```
perl -ne 'print unless $c>2; ++$c if /foo/' 
perl -ne '++$c if /foo/; print unless $c>2'
```

with/without keep.

Comment: The example had only 3 foos but if more ever occur you need `unless $c>=3`

Comment: True, of course.
Thanks for spotting---fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer: you could do this from vim. You could do this with vim as a text editor, or as a command line tool. As a text editor (with and without the line):

```
/foo<cr>2ndG:wq<cr>
/foo<cr>2njdG:wq<cr>
```

Some important details: `<cr>` means "enter". Also, you should in general do `<n-1>ndG` to delete after the "N'th" occurence. You asked for 3, so I wrote 2 in the example.

You could also do this purely from the command line.

```
vim -c "/foo" -c "normal 2ndG" -c "wq"
vim -c "/foo" -c "normal 2njdG" -c "wq"
```

This approach will also work with regular expressions. [This site](http://vimregex.com) provides a nice explanation of the vim flavor of regex.